# Can I patch the patch?

Tags: diff, patch

In our CI we are patching files, the problem appears when we make changes in files which we patch, can I applay commit changes to patch file?

example:

text.txt

```
A
B
C
D
```

patch.patch

```
+++ b/text2.txt
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
 A
 B
-C
+X
 D
```

new.txt:

```
Y
Y
B
C
D
```

diff text.txt new.txt > text_to_new.diff

```
diff --git a/text.txt b/new.txt
index 8422d40..4780582 100644
--- a/text.txt
+++ b/new.txt
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
-A
+Y
+Y
 B
 C
 D
```

Can I update patch.patch with text_to_new.diff?

Comment: Why not apply the patches in order?

Comment: I am using it in CI: I have the newest repo version and need to make same changes in code in order to test it (change same IPs and patch do files), so I can not run it in order.